# Checkbox created dynamically always does not return proper values(True/False)

Tags: excel, vba

i have a form with control's created dynamically. One of the control i.e the checkbox does not give proper value when i try to fetch the value; sometimes and most of the times it gives false even when "checked". Please find the snippet

```
Sub temp_gauge_popups()

    Dim shDatabase As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim itr As Long
    Dim mydate1 As Date
    Dim mydate2 As Long
    Dim datetoday1 As Date
    Dim datetoday2 As Long
    Dim msgstring As String
    Dim record_count As Long
    frmTmpGauges.Show vbModeless
    Dim theLabel1 As Object
    Dim theLabel2 As Object
    Dim theLabel3 As Object
    Dim theLabel4 As Object
    Dim inc As Integer
    Dim flag As Integer
    Dim num As Long

    Set shDatabase = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
    lastrow = [Counta(Database!A:A)]

    inc = 0
    record_count = 0
    datetoday1 = Date
    datetoday2 = datetoday1
    flag = 0
    num = 1

    For itr = 2 To lastrow

        mydate1 = shDatabase.Cells(itr, 19).Value
        mydate2 = mydate1

        If Trim(shDatabase.Cells(itr, 19).Value) <> "" Then

            If shDatabase.Cells(itr, 17).Value = "Temporary" And (mydate2 + shDatabase.Cells(itr, 18).Value) <= datetoday2 Then

                record_count = record_count + 1
                flag = 1

                Set theLabel1 = frmTmpGauges.Controls.Add("Forms.Textbox.1", "Type_of_Gauge" & record_count, True)
                With theLabel1
                    .Value = shDatabase.Cells(itr, 3).Value
                    .Left = 18
                    .Width = 150
                    .Height = 18
                    .Top = 54 + inc
                    .TextAlign = 1
                    .BackColor = &HC0FFFF
                    .BackStyle = 0
                    .BorderStyle = 1
                    .BorderStyle = 0
                    .Locked = True
                    .ForeColor = &HC00000
                    .Font.Size = 9
                    .TabIndex = itr - 1
                End With

                Set theLabel2 = frmTmpGauges.Controls.Add("Forms.Textbox.1", "Identification" & record_count, True)
                With theLabel2
                    .Value = shDatabase.Cells(itr, 4)
                    .Left = 175
                    .Width = 132
                    .Height = 18
                    .Top = 54 + inc
                    .TextAlign = 1
                    .BackColor = &HC0FFFF
                    .BackStyle = 0
                    .BorderStyle = 1
                    .BorderStyle = 0
                    .Locked = True
                    .ForeColor = &HC00000
                    .Font.Size = 9
                    .TabIndex = itr
                End With

                Set theLabel3 = frmTmpGauges.Controls.Add("Forms.Textbox.1", "Issued_To" & record_count, True)
                With theLabel3
                    .Value = shDatabase.Cells(itr, 16)
                    .Left = 299
                    .Width = 54
                    .Height = 18
                    .Top = 54 + inc
                    .TextAlign = 2
                    .BackColor = &HC0FFFF
                    .BackStyle = 0
                    .BorderStyle = 1
                    .BorderStyle = 0
                    .Locked = True
                    .ForeColor = &HC00000
                    .Font.Size = 9
                    .TabIndex = itr + 1
                End With

                Set theLabel4 = frmTmpGauges.Controls.Add("Forms.Checkbox.1", "chkboxrcvd" & record_count, True)
                With theLabel4
                    .Left = 390
                    .Width = 12.5
                    .Height = 18
                    .Top = 52 + inc
                    .TextAlign = 2
                    .TabIndex = itr - 2

                End With

            End If

    End If

    If flag = 1 Then

        inc = inc + 18
        flag = 0

    End If

    Next

frmTmpGauges.cmdUpdateTG.Top = 66 + (18 * record_count)
frmTmpGauges.Height = 138.75 + (18 * record_count)

frmForm.txtTempRecordCnt.Value = record_count

End Sub
```

```
Private Sub cmdUpdateTG_Click()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim oneControl As Object
    Dim itr3 As Integer

    itr3 = 1

For Each oneControl In frmTmpGauges.Controls
If TypeName(oneControl) = "CheckBox" Then

            If oneControl.Name = "chkboxrcvd" & itr3 Then
                MsgBox "chkboxrcvd" & itr3
                MsgBox oneControl.Value
                If oneControl.Value = True Then
                    shSearch.Cells(itr3, 4) = "Received"
                    itr3 = itr3 + 1
                Else
                    shSearch.Cells(itr3, 4) = ""
                    itr3 = itr3 + 1

                End If
            End If
        End If
```

[image]

As seen in the snapshot, even when the checkbox is checked it shows "False" as value. Any help will be much appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are the checkboxes generated? Can you include that code? The only thing I can imagine how this could happen is that you think the first checkbox is `chkboxrcvd1` but it is not the top one in that list. VBA doesn't lie, if it says the value is `False` then it is.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ i have added the code

Comment: just a note: You don't need that `flag` stuff if you just put `inc = inc + 18` right below `End With` of `theLabel4`. • The code doesn't look wrong to me. That should work.

Comment: Maybe the message is from the last time through the loop?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ : sure thanks..

Comment: @BrianMStafford Yes could be the case, but how do we deal with it?

Comment: @AtulPatil Did you check my answer below?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ yeah just saw.. I will update you shortly.. thank you :)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ still not success buddy. but what I observed is whenever I rerun the code the values do become "True". i dunno what's happening behind the scenes.

Comment: @AtulPatil In my test case it worked perfectly. Do you have any events that could interfere?

Comment: @AtulPatil, is there a reason you use `vbModeless`?

Comment: @HTH there is a sub routine that calls the dynamic form and also consists of the code to dynamically populate the controls on the form.

Comment: @AtulPatil, ok, but why modeless? I suspect it might be involved in your issue

Comment: Oh yeahh @HTH i removed the vbmodeless it seems to fix the true false issue...however now the issue is I have 2 userforms popping one blank and the other which i expect(with the dynamic textboxes) why would that be?

Comment: it's up to when/how/how many times your code instantiate userforms. you should post the relevant part of codes that show how the code flows

Comment: I have figured the rubbish part that I had done couple of days back - a small line screwed me big time. I had called my sub routine twice, that is the reason why I had double the number of controls. I have removed the extra call.  @HEH Thanks a lot for you time . appreciate that.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thank you buddy for your time too. Best of Luck

Comment: @AtulPatil, so the solution was to trace userform calls and eliminate the extra ones?

Comment: @HTH some what yes.. but the ides given by PEH also help me.. and your response(when/how/how many times your code instantiate userforms) gave me a clue that I should probably check what I have called the sub routine.

Comment: I see… glad you solved your problem, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following and check the output in the immediate window.
    Option Explicit

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim itr3 As Long
    itr3 = 1

    Do
        Dim OneControl As Object
        On Error Resume Next
            Set OneControl = frmTmpGauges.Controls("chkboxrcvd" & itr3)
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Do
        On Error GoTo 0

        If OneControl.Value = True Then
            Debug.Print itr3, "Recieved"
        Else
            Debug.Print itr3, "---"
        End If
        itr3 = itr3 + 1

    Loop
    On Error GoTo 0 'needed because of exit do!
End Sub
```

The way you loop might fail because `For Each oneControl In frmTmpGauges.Controls` might not have the controls in the correct order numbered from `1…10` (for 10 controls) but eg like `2, 1, 3, 5, 4, …` but your loop only works for them beeing in correct order `1…10`

The way this loop here works will output them in `1…10` always.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that when I loop through the dynamic controls the count of these control is twice that what it should eg. here i have 5 checkbox control but i get 10 counts. Any reasons why?